# How do I pass multiple values in URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My News model:
`has_one :category`

Category model:
`belongs_to :news`

Scope looks like this:

```
scope :category, -> (category_name) { joins(:category).where('categories.name = ?', category_name)}
```

Index action of the News controller:

```
def index
  news = News.filter(params.slice(:tag, :category, :days_ago))
  render json: news
 end
```

How can I pass multiple Categories in the url in order to show news which have those categories?
like this `/?category=lorem,ipsum,dolor` or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

params passing (important thing here is `[]` at the end of var name):

```
params: { 'categories[]': ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor'] }
```

url:

```
?categories[]= lorem&categories[]=ipsum&categories[]=dolor
```

which in params would look as

```
"categories"=>['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor']
```

Comment: Passed params in the url like you said. Didn't work
`Started GET "/news?categories[]=lorem&categories[]=ipsum` 
which produced the following sql `SELECT "news".* FROM "news"`

but it should have selected only news with provided categories

Comment: where do you parse the params? How should I know how you use it? :)

Comment: @RomanKanafotskiy you should do: `Model.where(category: params[:categories])`

Comment: @RomanKanafotskiy just in case, your scope should be changed `scope :category, -> (category_names) { joins(:category).where('categories.name IN (?)', category_names)}` if you use the array of categories here